# Getting not found error on new route laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, routes, fetch-api

I have my code to check if the name exist in my table here

```
validateName() {
                    var url = "{{ route('admin.port.check.name', ':name') }}";
                    url = url.replace(':name', this.name);

                    console.log(url);

                    fetch(url, {
                        method: 'GET',
                        headers: {
                            "X-CSRF-TOKEN": "{{ csrf_token() }}"
                        }
                    }).then(response => response.json()).then(data => {
                        console.log(data);
                    })
                }
```

I Have specified my route here
[image]

with the function like this

```
public function CheckName($name)
    {
        $port = Port::where('name', $name)->firstOrFail();
        if ($port) {
            return response()->json([
                'status' => "found"
            ]);
        }
        return response()->json([
            'status' => "not found"
        ]);
    }
```

I have checked the route list[image]

Anyone pls help me:(, it's returning this[image]

Comment: Did you cache your route?

Comment: If yes, you can try to clear cache

Comment: I know that your route has namespace `admin.port.etc...` since the url has `/admin` your actual route might be wrapped inside another route group with prefix `admin`. Check if that is the case and if it has a `name(`.. Meaning instead of just `admin.port.xxx` you might need something like `admin.admin.port.xxx` if the prefix's name is also `admin`

Comment: Do you have the name "tan" in database? It looks like 404 error generated from this line.

       ` $port = Port::where('name', $name)->firstOrFail();` if it won't find the name that's a 404 error, if it was route? It would have thrown HTTP route not found error

Comment: 1. yes i've clear the cache

Comment: and for the route, it's already pointing to a correct url, and also i have name "tan" inside my database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change

```
$port = Port::where('name', $name)->firstOrFail();
```

as this is returning 404 if resource is not found;

with

```
$port = Port::where('name', $name)->first();
```

Comment: Thanks, in my case i changed it to

```
$port = Port::where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $name . '%')->firstOrFail();
```

and now it's working

Comment: Danenda  please read 
how firstOrFail is working  https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent
Sometimes you may wish to throw an exception if a model is not found. This is particularly useful in routes or controllers. The findOrFail and firstOrFail methods will retrieve the first result of the query; however, if no result is found, an Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException will be thrown:
$flight = Flight::findOrFail(1);
$flight = Flight::where('legs', '>', 3)->firstOrFail();
If the ModelNotFoundException is not caught, a 404 HTTP response is automatically sent back to the client:

Comment: thanks, I've changed it to first

$port = Port::where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $name . '%')->first();
        if (!$port) {
            return $this->return_bool(false);
        }
        return $this->return_bool(true);

now it's working